# Losing focus on SurfaceView after Home button is pressed

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-activity

I'm developing a game based on this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-game-development-tutorials.html) .
I managed to make most of the game to work, but when the user presses home button, my game keeps running in the background, and I can pause it using the onPause method, and everything but it never runs the onResume method.

When the user restarts the game, none of the methods is called, and my panel has lost the focus.

How can i make it get the focus again, after the game was sent to background after the Home Button was pressed?

My Activity Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    panel = new Panel(this);
    // requesting to turn the title OFF
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen        
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // set our MainGamePanel as the View
    setContentView(panel);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}



     @Override
 public void onStart(){
     super.onStart();
     Log.d(TAG,"onStart");
 }

 @Override
 public void onRestart(){
     super.onRestart();
     Log.d(TAG,"onRestart");

 }
 @Override
 public void onResume(){    
     super.onResume();
     Log.d(TAG, "onResume");        
 }

 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstance");      
 }

 @Override
 public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstance");     
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     Log.d(TAG,"onpause");      
 }


 @Override
 public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  Log.d(TAG, "onStop..");
 }


 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy...");
 }
```

My Panel Constructor :

```
 WhackEmPanel(Context c) {
  super(c); 
  this.context=c;
  loadAnimations();
  setCharacters();
  getHolder().addCallback(this);
  backGround = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background); 
  // create the game loop thread
  thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);  
  setFocusable(true);      
  //Generate Random Numbers for characters
  Picker = RandomPicker.RandomPick(8,500); //From 0 to 8, gives me 500 random integers
  picked=Picker.remove(0); 
 }
```

I'm new to this gaming programming thing, but as far as I understood I need to call setFocusable(true) again, but where?

EDIT: After the suggestion from DizzyThermal I removed the pause method, leaving just the log, and I don't understand why it never reaches the onResume() method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. When the home button was pressed, my gameloop Thread was still running, onStop was never called, and I'm guessing the activity was never properly stopped. Now my onPause method actually finishes the Thread execution and I run into the Lunar Lander example bug.

This [Blog](http://wonton-games.blogspot.com/2010/06/lunar-lander-resume-game-workaround.html) helped me solving the bug by adding the following code to my surface creator:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

  Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
 \\ <-- added fix
  if(thread.getState()== Thread.State.TERMINATED){
      thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this); 
      thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();
 // <-- added fix
     }else {
  thread.setRunning(true);  //original code
  thread.start();           //original code
     }
 }
```

My onPause method now actually stops the game Thread execution.

```
 public void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     panel.stopPLaying();
     Log.d(TAG,"onpause");      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the **onResume()** method **protected**, try making it **public**..

Also, try moving the `super.onResume();` to the top of the method..  I'm pretty sure that it needs to be the first thing called in the "*Overriden*" function..

Comment: No.. it didn't help. It still doesn't reach onResume, or any other of the Overriden methods. I've edited my answer to the way the code is right now.

Comment: You still have `panel.pauseGame(false);` before `super.onResume();`  The Android Activity Lifecycle should reach onPause() when Home is hit  (possibly farther depending how long you wait before returning) and when it is brought back it must go through onResume() to continue running.. super.onResume() is included to have the method do what it would normally do.. This is what it would do if you didn't override it.  This is why it is normally included as the first thing to be done..

Comment: It still doesn't change anything, with or without the pauseGame, the Log still doesn't give me onResume, onRestart, onStart, nothing. After i come back after pressing home, none of the methods is called. And I don't understand why.